# Update or insert null value in uniqueidentifier column

Tags: c#, sql-server, updatecommand

I have a SQL Server database with a table that has a `uniqueidentifier` column `InputID` that allows null values.

In my C# project, I am passing the value of `InputID` as `object InputID` to my `SqlDataAdapter` and there I am parsing the object as `Guid` if it is not null.

```
sqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@InputID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier)).Value = InputID == null ? null : Guid.Parse(InputFromTestCaseID.ToString());
```

Unfortunately the

```
InputID == null ? null : Guid.Parse(InputFromTestCaseID.ToString());
```

throws an error

> CS8370 Feature 'target-typed conditional expression' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 9.0 or greater.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't want to pass null to your database anyway, you want to pass `System.DBNull.Value`

Comment: You probably have to cast everything to an object, since C# doesn't handle null guids but SQL Server does e.g. `InputID == null ? (object)System.DBNull.Value : (object)Guid.Parse(InputFromTestCaseID.ToString())`

Comment: @DaleK, That did the trick! Thanks a million.

Answer (score 2):

The error message should read: "null is not a Guid, so I have no idea what you want me to do"

I'm not exactly sure if this will work (didn't try)

```
sqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@InputID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier)).Value = (Guid.TryParse(InputFromTestCaseID.ToString(), out var value) ? value : null);
```

Otherwise, first create a nullable Guid as a value-container.